# How to get Google Drive working in Kubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, google-drive

I have installed KUbuntu 16.04 LTS with all updates.

I opened their dash menu and tried to search for Google. This leads me to icon named

> [image: Online Accounts]
>   *Configure your internet accounts such as Google, Live, Owncloud*
>   Online Accounts

- it has executable `kcmshell5 kcm_kaccounts`.

I clicked on it, *Online Accounts --- KDE Control Module* window opened and I added my Google account here, it asked my credentials and then I checked all checkboxes (including GoogleDrive).

But I can't find any mention of Google Drive in the KDE/Plasma interface. How can I access it from Dolphin (or Nemo, or Caja) or somewhat?

Comment: Would https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/kde-google-drive-integration-in-plasma help?

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be too new for 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Sorry about that! Looks like that link refers to 17.04+.

Comment: Just tested it in Kubuntu 18.04 LTS - it works great in Dolphin!

Comment: You just need to type `gdrive:/` in the Dolphin location bar.

Comment: Are you answering about Kubuntu **16.04 LTS**? On my system it says *Invalid protocol* after I enter `gdrive:/` in Dolphin location bar.

Answer (score 0):

**KIO seemed to solve the problem - https://community.kde.org/KIO_GDrive**
Not sure why this step is needed in addition to the Settings though.